# StringBuilder.Append deleting '\r' and '\n' tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im builiding colorized string in my `cshtml`.

```
StringBuilder colorizedOutput = new StringBuilder();
string concreteChar = outputArray[j] == ' ' ? "&#160;" : outputArray[j].ToString();

string htmlSpan = "<span " + "style=" + '"' + $"background-color: {color};" + "color:white;" + '"' + ">" + concreteChar + "</span>";
colorizedOutput.Append(htmlSpan);
@Html.Raw(colorizedOutput.ToString())
```

Each character in this string is an `span`.

My `htmlSpan` with `"\r"` tag look like this:

```
"<span style=\"background-color: red;color:white;\">\r</span>"
```

but `.Appned` method saving it like this:

```
"<span style=\"background-color: red;color:white;\"></span>"
```

Like you see, `\r` tag disappear.

My question is, how to deal with `\r\n` tags in `StringBuilder`?

Comment: What do you exactly need ?  Do you want to render new line ?  OR you want to show \r in the HTML text ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari i want to show this '\r' in view. For example, i want to show `"text\r\n"` as raw string, not as `text` and new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append a string to StringBuilder all escaping characters are removed. You can do something like below to keep them.

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 var html = "<span style=\"background-color: red;color:white;\">\\r</span>";
 sb.Append(html);
```

Note that I have changed `\r` to `\\r`.

**Output**

When you try to call `sb.ToString()`

```
<span style="background-color: red;color:white;">\r</span>
```

Comment: What if i want ` @Html.Raw(colorizedOutput.ToString())` after all? that tags will still appear in my string?

Comment: Yes, output for above example will be `<span style="background-color: red;color:white;">\r</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the htmlspan as

```
string htmlSpan = $"<span style='background-color: {color};color:white;>{concreteChar}</span>";
```

this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

*it works*

```
var someString = @"Chunk1 \r\n Chunk2";
var color = "red";
var colorizedOutput = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var ch in someString.ToCharArray())
{
    var concreteChar = ch == ' ' ? "&#160;" : ch.ToString();
    var htmlSpan = "<span " + "style=" + '"' + $"background-color: {color};" + "color:white;" + '"' + ">" + concreteChar + "</span>"+"\n";
    colorizedOutput.Append(htmlSpan);
}
Console.WriteLine(colorizedOutput.ToString());
```

[This is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZo5m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use of Environment.NewLine Property

Something like

```
StringBuilder colorizedOutput = new StringBuilder();
colorizedOutput.AppendFormat("<span style=\"background-color: red;color:white;\">{0} 
</span>", Environment.NewLine);
string s = sb.ToString();
```